# Why is "Community" shown as the modifying user on a question in the Unanswered view?

Tags: support, community-user

When I point to https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+redefine+FrontEndEventActions%3F, I see:

[image: screenshot]

When I point to https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=2&tab=mytags, I see:

[image: screenshot]

(I am sorry it is not useful if you don't share tags with me.)
Please note the difference in author and modification date.

The question in question is [How to redefine FrontEndEventActions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673277/how-to-redefine-frontendeventactions)

Why?

Comment: I'm sure you did -- but just to check, did you refresh your browser cache for both views?  I'm not seeing the modification by Community on June 17th.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is the text right above the user that you're not seeing

> Asked Apr 15 at 6:49

verus

> modified Jun 17 at 3:45

Community bumped it, or someone anonymized it.

This is how the views have always been.

Comment: Pretty sure he's asking, why the different attribution when viewed from both of his two searches. I.e., why is the *Community* edit visible only from the second link. It's not visible from the question's edit history, btw; I have a feeling it's not **meant** to be visible anywhere, being just a bump.

Comment: Cos he asked from two different views, but yes, you're right, that's likely something I overlooked.

Comment: @Michael Yep. You are right. Feel free to edit my question to clarify it. Also, I thought a bump would not be visible.

Comment: bel, Shog9 did a pretty good job with his title rephrase.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Well, *someone* has to own the bump activity. That view displays questions in the same way that the frontpage does, and it's not unexpected that the Community user is listed as the activity source there.

Comment: @Tim, it seems strange for a modification to be visible in one view, and yet not visible from the post's own revision history.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I think showing an actionless revision would probably be more confusing. Perhaps the bump could appear in the timeline view though (granted that wouldn't help too many people)? You can't really not show the Community user bump as a last-activity, since then the post would have no business being where it is on activity-sorted views. As a side note, this also is an issue when people delete answers, since it shows as last-activity, but only 10K+ users can see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note the difference in author and modification date.

In the first screenshot is shown the author of the question, the user who asked the question.
In the second screenshot is shown the user who has last modified the question, which also includes who answered the question.

In this case, the user is [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), who is not a real person, but occasionally touches the "modified by" record of questions that don't have an accepted or up-voted answer to "bump" them (move it toward the top of recently-modified lists).

Note that the Community user can *also* appear to have modified a question when an anonymous user proposes an edit that has been accepted (since there's no user name to attribute the edit to). However, this did not happen here.

Comment: An anonymous edit would show right now. It doesn't.

Comment: Right, but that is something you notice when you look at the question revision, not at the page shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case it means nothing.

Comment: It means something, as it is one of the two cases where Community is seen as user who modifies a post. If that didn't happen in this case is a different topic; Community can still appears as user that modified a post, if the proposed edit made from an anonymous user has been accepted.